# How can I set a value for the key "homepage" without using the API?

Tags: git, github, github-api, github-pages

When I get the data of an repository via the API there is this key "homepage" which is "null" in my cases. Is there any way to to set a value for it e.g. the URL of the gh-page of this repo without using the API? Maybe via the settings of the repo or the config file or doing something like 'git config homepage "http://USERNAME.github.io/REPO/" '

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you have access to the repository, click "Edit" from the repository header in your account, then enter you can change the homepage and description.

[image]

Comment: m( (face palming) Thank you very much! This was exactly what I was looking for.